# Join list and single string

Tags: c#

Why this input:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "a","b","c"
};

var out1 = string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => t));
var out2 = string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => t), "d");

Console.WriteLine("out1 = " + out1);
Console.WriteLine("out2 = " + out2);
```

gives that output:

```
out1 = a, b, c
out2 = System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.String], d
```

I don't understand why I got:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.String]
```

in `out2`. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you expecting?

Comment: `out2 = a, b, c, d`

Comment: try this : var out2 = string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => t).Append("d"));

Comment: I don't believe you need `.Select(t => t)` since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and that's what `string.Join` takes, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second example is calling [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Object___):

```
public static string Join(string? separator, params object?[] values);
```

So your second and third argument are being passed as an `object[]` here:

```
var out2 = string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => t), "d");
```

`string.Join` is internally calling `ToString()` on each item in the array, hence the output.

---

If you want to append a single string to the list, you could use [`Enumerable.Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append):

```
var out2 = string.Join(", ", list.Append("d"));
```

Which would call [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__):

```
public static string Join(
    string? separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?> values);
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because you're using two different overloads of `string.Join()` in the first one you're using the one which accepts an `IEnumerable` such as the one you obtain from `list.Select(t => t)` , the second one the compiler tries to use the one that wants an array of objects as the extra parameters, then it joins the two objects you are passing: the `list.Select(t => t)` and `"d"`, i guess it uses `.ToString()` on both, and you get the Type name for the first

Answer (score 1):

You wrote an incorrect call for `string.Join`. Just create a new list with the `d` and then call `string.Join`:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "a","b","c"
};

var out1 = string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => t));

var listWithD = list.Select(t => t).ToList();
listWithD.Add("d");
var out2 = string.Join(", ", listWithD);

Console.WriteLine("out1 = " + out1);
Console.WriteLine("out2 = " + out2);
```

And the output will be:

```
out1 = a, b, c
out2 = a, b, c, d
```

If you need, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) documentation for `string.Join`.

Answer (score 0):

You get this result because `string.Join()` in the second case takes an array of arguments, which are separated by commas. You pass the first argument `list.Select (t => t)`, and the second `"d"`. The first one calls `ToString()` so you get a result like this